# Load runtime packages from standalone application

Tags: forms, delphi, runtime, package

I would like to confirm an issue with you.

The scenario is as follows. We have two systems. An old, which is a standalone executable and another, completely new, modularized with packages.

Is possible dynamically load a package in a standalone application?

Need to load a package that has a form and display in my old application.

In my test, the problem is that load package in standalone application form class is nil.

The code below explains the situation:

```
Procedure TForm3.LoadPackageTest;
Const
  CClass = 'TAboutBox';

Var
  phm: HModule;
  LFormClass: TPersistentClass;
  LForm: TCustomForm;

Begin
  phm := LoadPackage('C:\_Dev\MyProjTest\forminbpl\BPLS\TestPack.bpl');

  If phm <> 0 Then
    Try

      //the problem!!!
      //In StandAlone application, not found class.
      LFormClass := TPersistentClass(GetClass(CClass));


      If Assigned(LFormClass) Then
      Begin
        LForm := TCustomForm(TComponentClass(LFormClass).Create(Nil));
        LForm.ShowModal;
        LForm.Free;
      End;

    Finally
      UnloadPackage(phm);
    End
  Else
    ShowMessage('Package not found');
End;
```

Grateful.

Answer (score 0):

> Is possible dynamically load a package in a standalone application?

Yes it is. You need to obey the rules of runtime packages. Specifically that all packages, and the host executable, are compiled with the same version of Delphi, and all use runtime packages. And in order to be able to use `GetClass` from the host, you'll need to call `RegisterClass` in the package. This article appears to have all the necessary detail: http://edn.embarcadero.com/cn/article/27178

As to whether or not you will be able to show your form that all depends on whether or not you correctly  designed your packages to stand alone.

---

In the comments you add the crucial detail. You want the standalone application to be built without runtime packages. You cannot do that. If you want to use runtime packages this way, in order for there to be a single shared class registry, then all parties must use runtime packages.

Comment: David, thanks for your answer. About the structure of packages, it's all right. The problem that occurs is that the form class is not found when I load the package in the standalone application. 

In my app standalone, If I set it to "runtime packages" so everything works correctly.

Comment: Oh, now you've changed the question. You originally asked if it was possible. What are you asking now? My guess is that you did not register the class in the package. In the package do you do, `RegisterClass('TAboutBox')`?

Comment: Hi David. About your question, yes, I register class "TAboutBox" in Package. Alright. Sorry, maybe I have not been able to explain it. The problem is this. If I try to open this package into an EXE without checking the "Build runtime packages" option within the package does not work. Only works if I check the "Build runtime packages" option. 

My question is whether it is possible to open a package from another application, but on a standalone application (Build runtime packages = False).

Comment: You have to use runtime packages in your host. Otherwise how could `GetClass` work?

Comment: Then, referring to GetClass method, it will work on the startup of my package was also booting my unit. But when the executable that loads the package has the "Build with runtime packages = False" option, after loading the package, unit is not initialized and registered class. 

Therefore questioned as yet never had the need to do this. But I believe that you can not load the package and form if the executable that is calling the package is "Build with runtime packages = True". 

Anyway, thank you friend.

Comment: Unless you use runtime packages everywhere you have multiple class registries, multiple vcl instances etc. Are you even building everything with the same version of Delphi? You need to do what I said. Same version of Delphi everywhere. Everything built to use runtime packages.

Comment: Hi David. Yes. All applications run in Delphi XE. Same version of Delphi and framework. The difference is that a project is modularized and another not yet converted to packets. It's all in a single EXE. 

Were this, this program is a single EXE, we need to call a form from another system, which is already in packages. 

But based on the tests I did, I realized that you can not do that. All applications must be yes in order runtime packages and of course, the same version of Delphi.

Comment: What's what my answer says

Comment: I understand it. I just thought you did not understand my situation. 

But okay, is now clarified. 
Thank you.